# angularjs tab with custom template

Tags: angularjs

Hi i follow tab in angular js it's working fine

```
<section class="panel-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-init="activeTab = 'details'">
            <li ng-class="{ active: activeTab === 'details' }">
                <a ng-click="activeTab = 'details'" href="#">Details</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{ active: activeTab === 'options' }">
                <a ng-click="activeTab = 'options'" href="#">Options</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{ active: activeTab === 'other' }">
                <a ng-click="activeTab = 'other'" href="#">Other</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{ active: activeTab === 'details' }">Details tab content.</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{ active: activeTab === 'options' }">Options tab content.</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{ active: activeTab === 'other' }">Other tab content.</div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

But i want to call custom template insted of same page

Comment: use ng-show/ng-hide or ng-if

Comment: No i want to call from controller with template url

Comment: Then you can go UI router for nested views.

Comment: can you please tell me how i can call this

Comment: go through UI Router. https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dynamically include a tab's content based on the selected tab, you can use `ng-include`:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane"
         ng-include src="activeTab + '.html'">
</div>
```

This will cause it to include 'details.html' when the 'details' tab is selected, and so on.

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywL9x8cb/) for an example

Comment: can you please explain i am new from angularJs

Comment: See added jsfiddle

Comment: No iwant to call templete not this way

Comment: Then please explain what you do mean

Comment: I want to tab but content's are calling from some custom tmplete

Comment: What do you mean with 'custom template'

Comment: yes custom template only content call from some templete .html file